# Create webfont with static sized images (No vectors etc.)

Tags: javascript, html, css, fonts, font-face

is it possible to create some letter as image and use them as font ? The font should be exactly like the original. Just static size, no vectors to prevent Browser to mess it up.

```
A = [100x100 A.PNG]
C = [100x100 B.PNG]
...
```

Comment: As a real, actual web font, there's no way to do this... but you could just use a series of `<img>`s?

Comment: Yeah, i will write a javascript parser. Thanks for you hint.

Comment: Sounds to me like you want to create a spritesheet, right?